# Leaflet: How to enable long clicks? (have mousedown trigger multiple times the button)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mouseevent, keydown, long-press

I have a pretty nice integration of leaflet in my website, and would like to have a long mousedown trigger multiple times the action.
I have tried a few things and can't get it to work on either my custom easybuttons nor the Leaflet zoom controls.

Could anyone help?

I am guessing Leaflet's javascript disables the multiple actions until mouseup happens. I'd like to remove that.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easy task involving just a `mousedown` and `mouseup` event handlers, and a call to `setInterval` and `clearInterval`:

```
function thingToDoWhenTheButtonIsPressed() {
  console.log('something');
}

var mousedownInterval;

map.on('mousedown', function() {
  mousedownInterval = setInterval(thingToDoWhenTheButtonIsPressed, 500);
});

map.on('mouseup', function() {
  clearInterval(mousedownInterval);
});
```

You can see a [working example here](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/leku/edit?html,console,output).

Don't forget to consult the [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html), and MDN's [documentation about `window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and [about `window.clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).